# horizontal bootstrap 5 navbar with submenu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

I'm using bootstrap 5.

In my navbar I want show menus horizantally like inserted picture.

[show horizantally sub menus like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdVsp.jpg)

I want to use submenu for other sub menus 4 level.

How should I do this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>horizantally sub menus</title>
    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1s75buv9/5/

```
var pos = parseInt($('.linedUp').closest('.dropdown').position().left);
calcWidth = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    var width = 0;
    var maxWidth = $(document).width() - pos;
    $('.linedUp li').each(function(){
      width += parseInt($(this).outerWidth()) + 2;
      if( maxWidth < width){
        width -= parseInt($(this).outerWidth());
      }
      
    });
    $('.linedUp').css({
        width: width
    });
  }, 0);
    
}
```

```
.linedUp > li{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="calcWidth()">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu linedUp">
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Action 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

I created using **li**, then calculated the width dynamically.

Edit:

To add an extra level of submenu, simply add `.dropdown-submenu` to any `li` in an existing dropdown menu.

For example:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can further refer to [Official Bootstrap Website](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns) for more on navbars!